# Nested JSON with dynamic Key Values in LWC

Tags: javascript, json, salesforce, lwc

I have a JSON Data and I would like to iterate on `runStatus`, however not all the nodes have `runStatus` and I am getting error that `run.runStatus is Undefined`.

How can i fix the error in HTML?

```
[
    {
        "Code": "AB",
        "Run": {
            "Range": {
                "maxValue": "75",
                "minValue": "54"
            },
            "remarks": [],
            "runStatus": "RESULTED"
        }
    },
    {
        "Code": "CD",
        "Run": {
            "remarks": []
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

do a check before

```
if(YOUR_OBJ.Run.runStatus !== undefined)
{
  console.log(YOUR_OBJ.Run.runStatus);
  // ...
}
```